# Task C#, list of Tast<T> and Task.Wait()

Tags: c#, task

I have simple code and I would know answer:

```
List<Task<int>> list = new List<Task<int>>;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
  list.Add(new Task<int>((j) => return (int)j%2, i);

}

list.Foreach(t => t.Start());
```

And now I want to wait for all `Tasks`, well it's good idea?:

```
Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray());
```

P.S:

describtion about `WaitAll`:

```
public static void WaitAll(params Task[] tasks)
```

Comment: Not really, you are not doing enough work in the task to justify the cost. it would be faster just do it single threaded.

Comment: ok, but i need to know about this implementation:
Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray()) - it will be work for more works, f.e downloading zip file from server? I need to know that Task.WaitAll(list.ToArray()) works or not :-) ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's exactly what `Task.WaitAll` is for.

But if you know how many tasks you're going to have before creating them, you should stick to `Task[]` instead of `List<Task>` from the very beginning:

```
var tasks = new Task[10];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    var task = new Task<int>(x => return x % 2, i);
    tasks[i] = task;
    task.Start();
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

This allows you to skip moving from `List<T>` to `T[]` array back and forth.